# pass polars dataframe from rust to python and then return manipulated dataframe back to rust

Tags: python, rust

I have a rust program which is a usual backend program. It listens for computation request and forward some parameters(e.g. polars dataframe) to a python module with pyo3. The reason I need pyo3 is that python's ecosystem of data analysis is better. I have plenty of libs in python to do data work, for example scipy.

```
// main.rs
use polars::prelude::*;
use pyo3::{prelude::*, types::PyModule};

fn main() -> PyResult<()> {
    let code = include_str!("./test.py");

    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let activators = PyModule::from_code(py, code, "activators.py", "activators")?;

        let df: DataFrame = df!(
            "integer" => &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "float" => &[4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
        )
        .unwrap();

        let result = activators.getattr("test")?.call1((df,))?.extract()?;

        Ok(())
    })
}
```

```
# test.py
def test(x):
    # manipulate dataframe x and then return to rust
    return x
```

With above code I can pass rust native type to python. But with polars dataframe I have to implement some traits:

```
the trait bound `polars::prelude::DataFrame: IntoPy<Py<PyAny>>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `IntoPy<T>`:
  <bool as IntoPy<Py<PyAny>>>
  <char as IntoPy<Py<PyAny>>>
  <isize as IntoPy<Py<PyAny>>>
  <i8 as IntoPy<Py<PyAny>>>
  <i16 as IntoPy<Py<PyAny>>>
  <i32 as IntoPy<Py<PyAny>>>
  <i64 as IntoPy<Py<PyAny>>>
  <i128 as IntoPy<Py<PyAny>>>
and 193 others
required for `(polars::prelude::DataFrame,)` to implement `IntoPy<Py<PyTuple>>`
```

Is there any straightforward way to achieve my goal? Ideally passing polars dataframe to python is 0-copy, since polars also has a python implementation.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass and extract the dataframe as [`pyo3_polars::PyDataFrame`](https://docs.rs/pyo3-polars/latest/pyo3_polars/struct.PyDataFrame.html).