# ModuleNotFoundError trying pyo3 with virtualenv

Tags: python, rust

This question is a follow-up question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77626939/pass-polars-dataframe-from-rust-to-python-and-then-return-manipulated-dataframe/77627003#77627003).

```
// main.rs
use polars::prelude::*;
use pyo3::{prelude::*, types::PyModule};
use pyo3_polars::PyDataFrame;

fn main() -> PyResult<()> {
    let code = include_str!("./test.py");

    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let activators = PyModule::from_code(py, code, "activators.py", "activators")?;

        let df: DataFrame = df!(
            "integer" => &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "float" => &[4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
        )
        .unwrap();

        let relu_result: PyDataFrame = activators
            .getattr("test")?
            .call1((PyDataFrame { 0: df },))?
            .extract()?;

        Ok(())
    })
}
```

```
# test.py

def test(x):
    import pyarrow

    import sys
    print(sys.executable, sys.path)

    # manipulate dataframe x
    return x
```

```
[dependencies]
pyo3 = { version = "0.20.0", features = ["auto-initialize"] }
polars = "0.35.4"
pyo3-polars = "0.9.0"
```

I am trying pyo3 with virtualenv. I have a python env installed under the rust project root named `venv`.
According to pyo3's [doc](https://pyo3.rs/main/getting_started#virtualenvs), it supports virtualenv.

But:

```
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ cargo run
thread 'main' panicked at /Users/jack/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-polars-0.9.0/src/lib.rs:166:44:
pyarrow not installed: PyErr { type: <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, value: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'pyarrow'"), traceback: None }
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I have installed pyarrow in local virtual env.

---

Update 1:

```
# test.py
def test(x):
    # import pyarrow

    import sys
    print(sys.executable, sys.path, sys.prefix)

    # manipulate dataframe x
    return x
```

Comment out `import pyarrow`, `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run` still complains:

```
thread 'main' panicked at /Users/jack/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-polars-0.9.0/src/lib.rs:166:44:
pyarrow not installed: PyErr { type: <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, value: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'pyarrow'"), traceback: None }
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/std/src/panicking.rs:597:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/core/src/panicking.rs:72:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/core/src/result.rs:1652:5
   3: core::result::Result<T,E>::expect
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/core/src/result.rs:1034:23
   4: <pyo3_polars::PySeries as pyo3::conversion::IntoPy<pyo3::instance::Py<pyo3::types::any::PyAny>>>::into_py
             at /Users/jack/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-polars-0.9.0/src/lib.rs:166:23
   5: <pyo3_polars::PyDataFrame as pyo3::conversion::IntoPy<pyo3::instance::Py<pyo3::types::any::PyAny>>>::into_py::{{closure}}
             at /Users/jack/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-polars-0.9.0/src/lib.rs:182:22
   6: core::iter::adapters::map::map_fold::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/core/src/iter/adapters/map.rs:84:28
   7: <core::slice::iter::Iter<T> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::fold
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/core/src/slice/iter/macros.rs:232:27
   8: <core::iter::adapters::map::Map<I,F> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::fold
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/core/src/iter/adapters/map.rs:124:9
   9: core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator::for_each
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:857:9
  10: alloc::vec::Vec<T,A>::extend_trusted
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:2881:17
  11: <alloc::vec::Vec<T,A> as alloc::vec::spec_extend::SpecExtend<T,I>>::spec_extend
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/alloc/src/vec/spec_extend.rs:26:9
  12: <alloc::vec::Vec<T> as alloc::vec::spec_from_iter_nested::SpecFromIterNested<T,I>>::from_iter
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/alloc/src/vec/spec_from_iter_nested.rs:62:9
  13: <alloc::vec::Vec<T> as alloc::vec::spec_from_iter::SpecFromIter<T,I>>::from_iter
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/alloc/src/vec/spec_from_iter.rs:33:9
  14: <alloc::vec::Vec<T> as core::iter::traits::collect::FromIterator<T>>::from_iter
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:2749:9
  15: core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator::collect
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:2053:9
  16: <pyo3_polars::PyDataFrame as pyo3::conversion::IntoPy<pyo3::instance::Py<pyo3::types::any::PyAny>>>::into_py
             at /Users/jack/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-polars-0.9.0/src/lib.rs:178:24
  17: pyo3::types::tuple::<impl pyo3::conversion::IntoPy<pyo3::instance::Py<pyo3::types::tuple::PyTuple>> for (T0,)>::into_py
             at /Users/jack/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-0.20.0/src/types/tuple.rs:325:37
  18: pyo3::types::any::PyAny::call
             at /Users/jack/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-0.20.0/src/types/any.rs:513:20
  19: pyo3::types::any::PyAny::call1
             at /Users/jack/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-0.20.0/src/types/any.rs:587:9
  20: hello::main::{{closure}}
             at ./src/main.rs:17:40
  21: pyo3::marker::Python::with_gil
             at /Users/jack/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-0.20.0/src/marker.rs:434:9
  22: hello::main
             at ./src/main.rs:8:5
  23: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/79e9716c980570bfd1f666e3b16ac583f0168962/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

---

Update 2:

It looks like I have to comment out some rust code to get python sys info. After commenting out `PyDataFrame` related code in rust, I have:

```
/Users/jack/Workspace/rust/hello/target/debug/hello ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages'] /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11
```

Above is python's path info. It seems that pyo3 chooses this python 3.11 instead of using my local virtual env.

---

Update 3:

I switch to pyenv's virtualenv following [this](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv).

```
def test(x):
    import sys
    print(sys.executable, sys.path, sys.prefix)
    
    import pyarrow

    # manipulate dataframe x
    return x
```

But `pyarrow` is still missing after successfully installing it into pyenv's virtual env. LOL.

```
/Users/jack/Workspace/rust/hello/target/debug/hello ['/Users/jack/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python311.zip', '/Users/jack/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11', '/Users/jack/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/Users/jack/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/site-packages'] /Users/jack/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7
Error: PyErr { type: <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, value: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'pyarrow'"), traceback: Some(<traceback object at 0x106243a40>) }
```

execute test.py manually is fine:

```
python ./src/test.py
```

It looks like pyo3 can't resolve dependency.

Comment: If you remove the `import pyarrow` line, does the printed sys info indicate you are in the venv or the base Python interpreter?  I would also check `sys.prefix`

Comment: Nit: `PyDataFrame { 0: df }` is an arcane unused syntax. Use `PyDataFrame(df)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`pyo3` does respect virtual environments, but only when it comes as an extension module. When you're embedding Python you are all on your own, and by default it will use the global installation.

`pyo3` does not provide any API to change that, but Python does. So you can go down for the low-level C API and initialize Python yourself. That requires omitting the `auto-initialize` feature from PyO3.

Here's how you do it:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use pyo3::{prelude::*, types::PyModule};
use pyo3_polars::PyDataFrame;

fn init_pyo3_with_venv(env_dir: &str) {
    use std::mem::size_of;
    use std::ptr::addr_of_mut;

    use libc::wchar_t;
    use pyo3::ffi::*;

    unsafe {
        fn check_exception(status: PyStatus, config: &mut PyConfig) {
            unsafe {
                if PyStatus_Exception(status) != 0 {
                    PyConfig_Clear(config);
                    if PyStatus_IsExit(status) != 0 {
                        std::process::exit(status.exitcode);
                    }
                    Py_ExitStatusException(status);
                }
            }
        }

        let mut config = std::mem::zeroed::<PyConfig>();
        PyConfig_InitPythonConfig(&mut config);

        config.install_signal_handlers = 0;

        // `wchar_t` is a mess.
        let env_dir_utf16;
        let env_dir_utf32;
        let env_dir_ptr;
        if size_of::<wchar_t>() == size_of::<u16>() {
            env_dir_utf16 = env_dir
                .encode_utf16()
                .chain(std::iter::once(0))
                .collect::<Vec<_>>();
            env_dir_ptr = env_dir_utf16.as_ptr().cast::<wchar_t>();
        } else if size_of::<wchar_t>() == size_of::<u32>() {
            env_dir_utf32 = env_dir
                .chars()
                .chain(std::iter::once('\0'))
                .collect::<Vec<_>>();
            env_dir_ptr = env_dir_utf32.as_ptr().cast::<wchar_t>();
        } else {
            panic!("unknown encoding for `wchar_t`");
        }
        check_exception(
            PyConfig_SetString(
                addr_of_mut!(config),
                addr_of_mut!(config.prefix),
                env_dir_ptr,
            ),
            &mut config,
        );

        check_exception(Py_InitializeFromConfig(&config), &mut config);

        PyConfig_Clear(&mut config);

        PyEval_SaveThread();
    }
}

fn main() -> PyResult<()> {
    let env_dir = std::env::current_dir()?.join(".env");
    if !env_dir.is_dir() {
        panic!("please run from proper directory");
    }
    init_pyo3_with_venv(env_dir.to_str().unwrap());

    let code = include_str!("./test.py");

    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let activators = PyModule::from_code(py, code, "activators.py", "activators")?;

        let df: DataFrame = df!(
            "integer" => &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "float" => &[4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
        )
        .unwrap();

        let relu_result: PyDataFrame = activators
            .getattr("test")?
            .call1((PyDataFrame { 0: df },))?
            .extract()?;

        Ok(())
    })
}
```

And in Cargo.toml:

```ini
[dependencies]
pyo3 = "0.20.0"
polars = "0.35.4"
pyo3-polars = "0.9.0"
libc = "0.2.150"
```

Comment: too complicated, but thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally I found the issue. Put this inside test.py and install package.

```
def install(package):
    import pip
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', package])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', package])
```

Sometimes I have to install package manually with code. It magically solves this issue. LOL. Maybe new version of pyo3 will fix it.

Comment: This just installs the package globally, not in the virtual environment. You could as well do it manually.

Comment: I am not sure why. But this seems to install package into the virtual env. Manually installing won't help in my case.

Comment: Installing globally does help. I just checked it. Are you sure you weren't inside the virtual environment when you installed? Try removing the packages (because running this script already installed them) then running it again to see the error, then install it globally and it should work.